How is the change in internal energy zero for the following scenario:

in the problem, they are removing partitions one by one. when they remove the first partition they've mentioned in the solution that internal energy will remain constant in the process (and after removing the second i know it'll be constant as the gas is doing adiabatic free expansion so no work and hence no change in internal energy)
what I don't understand is, when the first partition is removed we can see gases expanding under some pressure so clearly some work is happening on both of them so from first law on system ∆Q = ∆U + ∆W now system is adiabatic so ∆Q = 0 => ∆W = -∆U, how do i even say the internal energy is constant here?
btw they gave Vo as the ans as they claim internal energy of system doesn't change

Since pressure  in  part 1 and part 2  are the same. there is not really "expansion, just mixing.

The internal energy change in mixing two pure ideal gases at pressure P and temperature T to arrive at a mixture at pressure P and temperature T is zero.  This can be shown using ideal semi-permeable membranes and cylinders with pistons.

We are told that the pressures on either side of partition 1 are the same. Also the average molecular speeds in the two chambers have been set so that the oxygen and nitrogen gases in chambers 1 and 2 are at the same temperature. By symmetry, neither gas can do work on the other once partition 1 is removed.
We are not told exactly how partition 1 is removed, but it is a reasonable assumption that it is removed in such a way that it does no work on the gases in chambers 1 or 2 either e.g. it is slid slowly out of the chamber.

i apologise if this a very silly question, but what about the expression work = integral of Pext • dV, volume is increasing of the gases and there's some Pext too why is this giving non zero work

@BobD use the average speed of molecules in maxwell distribution that is Vavg = √(8RT/πM) this shows they are on same temperature

@khanzaid I was asking gandalf61 to explain it for your benefit. But I see you already knew.

@khanzaid But why would you think the adiabatic expansion involves non zero net work?

Since the initial pressure and volume is the same in both partitions before the first partition is removed, no expansion work is done when the first partition is removed. The gases simply mix.
When the second partition is released the gas towards the rear loses internal energy as it expands doing positive work compressing the gas at the front causing it to gain an equal amount of internal energy, for net work and change in internal energy of zero.
Since the second partition moves horizontally and begins and ends at rest (after possibly some oscillations if the expansion is rapid) the change in kinetic energy of the second partition is zero. Per the work energy theorem the net work done on an object equals its change in kinetic energy. Thus the net work done on the partition by the gases is zero.
Thus overall we have net internal work and change in internal energy of the system equal to zero.
Hope this helps.
